# laravel send emails to mailtrap instead of gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-queue

in development environment i used mailtrap to test emails and evrything is OK.

I create digitalocean server for test online and I changed all mail settings from mailtrap to gmail, in .env and config/mail.php.

I try long time to send emails to real emails but its failed and send all emails to mailtrap inboxes.

I cleared every thing:

```
php artisan clear-compiled

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache

composer dump-autoload
```

Also I cleared all redis keys. But it send all emails to mailtrap.

Note the server is ubuntu 17.04

i test on my local server it is success and send to real emails.

what should i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using queues make sure you have restarted your queue worker. You should run

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

command to make queue process see the changes. More about this in [Queue Workers & Deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment)